# Using enumerate to return a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is the list that i should be using:

```
d_list(['a','b','c'])
```

and the return code should give me an output like this:

```
{‘a’:0, ‘b’:1, ‘c’:2}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate` for this, and *dictionary comprehension*:

```
def d_list(iterable):
    return { k: i for i, k in enumerate(iterable) }
```

Or you can for example do this with `dict(..)` and `map(..)`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def d_list(iterable):
    return dict(map(itemgetter(slice(None, None, -1)), enumerate(iterable)))
```

This then generates for example:

```
>>> d_list(['a', 'b', 'c'])
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def d_list(L):
return {key:value for value, key in enumerate(L)}
```

This should give you an output of :
{‘a’:0, ‘b’:1, ‘c’:2}

Answer (score 1):

```
def d_list(l):
    return dict(map(reversed, enumerate(l)))

d_list(['a','b','c'])
# {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a less obscure version of using `dict(..)` @Willem if your version of Python does not support the dictionary comprehension:

```
def d_list(L):
    return dict( (v,i) for i,v in enumerate(L) )
```

If you want to do it without generators you can use the list comprehension

```
def d_list(L):
    return dict( [ (v,i) for i,v in enumerate(L) ] )
```